# Error using fontspec/lualatex with italic IPA unicode symbol <ɻ> (retroflex approximant)

Tags: luatex, alignment, linguistics, tipa

Using fontspec with lualatex, and Libertine as the font, I get an obvious misalignment whenever the IPA symbol for a retroflex approximant, <ɻ>, is used in italics, but only if it has other characters in the argument to that command - either \textit{} or \emph{}.

See the MWE and result below:

```tex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

Why can I print \emph{ɻ} or \emph{a}\emph{ɻ}\emph{pa} correctly, but \emph{aɻpa} goes awry? 

\end{document}
```

[image: misalignment of IPA symbol]

Comment: looks like a fault in the font. Try libertinus instead.

Comment: I added a workaround as an answer to the duplicate question.